# Algunos fragments desaparecen al girar la pantalla en Android

Tags: android, fragment

tengo un cuatro fragments, al girar la pantalla desaparece uno, si giro nuevamente desaparecen dos y aparece el que faltaba en un principio y finalmente todos desaparecen a excepción de uno, lo más extraño de todo es que esto solo ocurre en una version de android inferior a la 23 o sea Marshmallow por que en la versión 23 funciona perfectamente, los fragments no desaparecen.

dejo unas capturas y mi build.gradle
Al iniciar
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Al girar por primera vez
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Este es mi build.gradle

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.alphemsoft.education.regression"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 11
        versionName "1.1"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
//        release {
//            minifyEnabled false
//            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
//        }

        release {
            debuggable false
            minifyEnabled true
//            shrinkResources true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }

        debug {
            debuggable true
            minifyEnabled true
//            shrinkResources true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }


    }
}

configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy.force 'com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:3.0.1'
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })

    //    compile 'com.github.bluejamesbond:textjustify-android:+'


    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:+'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:+'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:+'
    compile 'com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v3.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:+'
    compile 'com.codesgood:justifiedtextview:1.0.2'
    compile 'de.psdev.licensesdialog:licensesdialog:1.8.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:10.0.1'
    compile 'rongi.rotate-layout:rotate-layout:2.0.0'
    compile 'io.github.kobakei:ratethisapp:1.1.2'
    compile 'com.github.yavski:fab-speed-dial:1.0.7'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Gracias pro su ayuda de antemano

Este es el código que uso para crear el primer fragment

```
mBundle=new Bundle();
        mBundle.putBoolean("es_tablet",esTablet);
        main = getFragmentManager().getFragment(inState,"myfragment");
        miFragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_main, main).commit();
```

Este es el código que uso para pasar del primer fragment al segundo

```js
if (botonAceptarPulsado==true){
                mBundle.putBoolean("botonPulsado",botonAceptarPulsado);
//                fragmentDatos.setArguments(mBundle);

                if (fragmentDatos.getArguments()==null){
                    fragmentDatos.setArguments(mBundle);
                }else {
                    getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().detach(fragmentDatos).commit();
                    fragmentDatos.getArguments().putAll(mBundle);
                    getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().attach(fragmentDatos).commit();
                }
                botonAceptarPulsado=false;
            }else{
                mBundle.putBoolean("botonPulsado",botonAceptarPulsado);


//                getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().detach(fragmentDatos);
                if (fragmentDatos.getArguments()==null){
                    fragmentDatos.setArguments(mBundle);
                }else {
                    getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().detach(fragmentDatos).commit();
                    fragmentDatos.getArguments().putAll(mBundle);
                    getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().attach(fragmentDatos).commit();
                    if (tipoDeRegression.equals("lineal")){
                        ((RadioButton)fragmentDatos.getView().findViewById(R.id.rb_lineal)).setChecked(true);
                    }else if (tipoDeRegression.equals("potencial")){
                        ((RadioButton)fragmentDatos.getView().findViewById(R.id.rb_potencial)).setChecked(true);
                    }
                }
            }
```

Para ir del segundo al tercero

```
if (getResources().getBoolean(R.bool.es_tablet)==true){
                ((MainFragment)(getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("fragment_main"))).llenarListaDeArchivos();

                getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_resultados,resultadosFragmento).addToBackStack(null).commit();
```

Finalmente para ir del tercero al último

```
getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_graficos,graficoFragment).addToBackStack(null).commit();
```

Comment: Nunca he experimentado este problema determinado por la version del OS podrias agregar el codigo que usas para agregar el o los fragments?

Comment: @Jorgesys Lo edité, ahora tiene la información necesaria, gracias por su pronta respuesta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema residia en que se creaba una nueva instancia del fragment y por lo tanto este era "null" asi que hice que primero verifique si savedInstanceState era nulo, si lo era creaba el fragment, de lo contrario no lo hace y cada Fragment usa

```
setRetainInstance(true);
```

Y ya no sobreescribo el metodo onSaveInstanceState, mi problema fue solucionado, gracias a todos por su ayuda.

Answer (score 0):

Si estas usando ViewPager y suponiendo que este se llama visor, establece lo siguiente

```
    Visor.setOffscreenPageLimit(max_fragmentos);
```

max_fragmentos = int número fijo de fragmentos que quieres q se mantengan en memoria y asi no desaparecerán.